# Remotely triggering a Quartz job for an acceptance test?

Tags: unit-testing, jakarta-ee, automated-tests, integration-testing, quartz-scheduler

I am re-engineering a site from an existing site, and I am writing acceptance tests to prove out the Use cases and ensure that I don't lose any functionality. The site has several Quartz jobs that are triggered throughout the day, and perform processing for DB records.

For my test strategy, I have access to the existing site and the new site, my plan is to perform each of several use cases against the existing site, and when the tests pass I will be able to use those tests to verify the functionality of the new site.

Here is the catch...

I have the source code, but I will be running my test against the working site. What I would like to do is trigger the Quartz job that needs to be run, and then query the DB to ensure that all of the business rules and Use Case flows have been satisfied. Can I trigger Quartz jobs programmatically on a remote server in my acceptance tests, or is this an impossibility?

I am using JEE5, Quartz, Weblogic, Oracle, Selenium, and jUnit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, quartz has an rmi interface, and a jmx interface through which you can trigger the jobs.

Comment: any hints on doing that programmatically?

Comment: For RMI set the scheduler's properties that tell it to export itself via RMI, and then write your code to use the Scheduler API via RMI (examples for such ship with Quartz).

Comment: For JMX, set the scheduler's properties that tell it to export itself via JMX, then write code that looks up the JMX object and invokes methods on it.